# обновить Ubuntu с 16 до 22

Tags: ubuntu

Есть `Ubuntu 16 LTS`, ни разу не обновлялась. Сейчас прижало (некоторые программы перестают работать), хочу перейти на `22 LTS`.

Вопрос - это делается 'как обычно':

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt full-upgrade

sudo do-release-upgrade
```

или, в связи с пропуском нескольких версий, другие команды?

Comment: да там же где-то встроенный обновляльщик есть

Comment: 'встроенный обновляльщик' - как это?

Comment: Software Manager, Software Center, я уж не помню, как та утилита называется. Там где можно из репозиториев софт ставить и обновлять без терминала

Comment: Мне всегда казалось, что это "обновление софта" работает внутри релиза. То есть, если у тебя 16-я убунта - то хоть заобновляйся новыми версиями ноутпада (или что там вместо него в убунте?), но 16-у убунту - не трожь! Хоешь свежее? сноси и ставь заново из свежего дистрибутива.
Но - это я так думал, можете в меня кинуть чем то тяжелым, и написать, что это всё не так?

Comment: Эникейщик - это понятно.  Я имел в виду - можно ли перепрыгнуть через 2 LTS версии? Или будут траблы и лучше заранее вообще всё снести и переустановить всю Убунту. Или (совсем дичь) поставить 18 LTS, потом 20-ю, потом 22.

Comment: S.H. - конечно, периодически прилетало - есть новая LTS версия, хотите поставить? Но я имел глупость игнорировать.

Comment: Парни, спасибо за пояснения. Давно не имел дела с десктопом на убунте, вижу, что прогресс не остановить!